# Meals in the afternoon and different time zones

Tags: vinaya, eight-precepts

How do Buddhist monks deal with meals while traveling across different time zones?

Answer (score 3):

"Should any bhikkhu chew or consume staple or non- staple food at the wrong time, it is [an offence of Confession.]" (Paac. 37; BMC p.362).
 Here the **'wrong time' is defined to be from noon until dawn the following day**.

So regardless of which timezone a monk is in, he can consume food between dawn and noon. All you need to check is where the sun is.

Comment: @SankhaKulathatille Exactly sir, I know some monks who decide it by looking at the sun, because sun-rise and sun-set times may change during different seasons in the year.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have such problems when keeping Vinaya and abstain from using Yanas (vehicles, burden others with their traveling in not suitable ways), so the question is actually not proper but a result of wrong conduct at first place already. See also [Pāṭimokkha for 21st century](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/31826/p%c4%81%e1%b9%adimokkha-for-21st-century/?lastactivity)

When slight things are made wrong, it grows larger and larger and becomes pointless.